# How to automatically sanitize ActiveStorage Blob filenames on or before upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am using `ActiveStorage` on a large Rails app and the client seems to be unable to sanitize their own filenames from non-url-safe characters. I cannot find a way to do this automatically within the framework itself. I would rather not just output a sanitized filename when the file URL is output on the frontend, as that might be confusing to other developers debugging issues later on.

`ActiveStorage::Blob.filename` returns a `Filename` instance which has a `sanitized` method on it, however I cannot seem to see where it is actually used?

Blob::filename: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L139

```
  # Returns an ActiveStorage::Filename instance of the filename that can be
  # queried for basename, extension, and a sanitized version of the filename
  # that's safe to use in URLs.
  def filename
    ActiveStorage::Filename.new(self[:filename])
  end
```

Filename: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/filename.rb#L57

```
  # Returns the sanitized filename.
  #
  #   ActiveStorage::Filename.new("foo:bar.jpg").sanitized # => "foo-bar.jpg"
  #   ActiveStorage::Filename.new("foo/bar.jpg").sanitized # => "foo-bar.jpg"
  #
  # Characters considered unsafe for storage (e.g. \, $, and the RTL override character) are replaced with a dash.
  def sanitized
    @filename.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: "�").strip.tr("\u{202E}%$|:;/\t\r\n\\", "-")
  end
```

The `Rails` docs describe how to `attach` files, however this is for individual files and wouldn't suitable if the client is uploading multiple files at once:

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects

Another SO Question asked something similar, but requires the record to be updated, rather than sanitizing on create:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52957480/3588645

Another medium article suggests adding an after save on a model, but the app uses multiple attachment names per model and multiple models with attachments, so again, this would not be a suitable solution:

https://medium.com/fiatinsight/how-to-change-a-filename-in-rails-active-storage-f3e4f26f427e

I feel like this should be pretty simple, however its proving to be quite the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.